# How to have hair on a rigged model?

Tags: animation, particles, hair

I have a model that is rigged and I have been trying to find a way to add hair to the model. I added a hair particle system for the hair, eyebrows, and eyelashes directly onto the model but when I go to animate the model with the rig the hair systems don't stay attached to where they should stay. So what would be the best way to go about adding hair?

Comment: I may have been wrong in my answer. I am pretty sure that once you actually start playing the animation, unless you’ve already baked the cache in some way, the hair should update to the proper position when its modifier is before the armature modifier.

Comment: @TheLabCat I just made a quick animation testing that and the hair is still being weird, is there something I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Well, yes. Hair seems to be one of those things that’s right on the border of what the computer can do, but thankfully it’s on the homeward side of that border. Please add some screenshots to show exactly what’s going on. One of the things I strongly suspect is that for some reason the cache is not refreshing.

Comment: Hope an Imgur link is okay. I rendered the model doing just a blink animation to show the problem. https://imgur.com/a/Fobn7RW

Comment: first off, Imgur is the default image upload service when adding images to questions. Secondly, that is weird. I notice that most of the hair is staying where it is. Is it possible that a vertex group meant to control hair properties is being affected by the armature? Can you reproduce the problem with a more basic model, and then upload that via blend-exchange.com

Comment: @TheLabCat Sorry for the late reply I took a few days away from this project. I think the issue is that I don't have a hair cap for anything on the character. I will update you and the post if the haircap fixes the issues.

Comment: @TheLabCat so what I did to fix the issue was remove the forehead bones and add a hair cap for the hair and added some weights to the eyebrows so they move more smoothly.